# Distributing source code with different licenses in a single page

Tags: source-code, documentation, redistribution

I'm writing a web application (hobby project) that aggregates documentations and source code of arbitrary artifacts (from Maven Central) and (possibly) present them to the user in a single web page, side by side. I am planning to host the app at my server for the general public when I am finished writing it.

I think I won't have any trouble redistributing something that is found in Maven Central as-is, there are plenty of mirrors and software that does just that. What I am worried is that if the user requests two artifacts with have incompatible licenses with each other(Apache 2 and GPL 2 for example, though I am sure there are lots of incompatible combinations), and that the source code and/or api documentations (javadoc) get presented in a single page.

I am aware of this statement I found while reading GPL2, so I think I'm fine with this particular license though.

> In addition, mere aggregation of another work not based on the Program with the Program (or with a work based on the Program) on a volume of a storage or distribution medium does not bring the other work under the scope of this License.

I would like to know if there is anything that I should take caution when redistributing source code or api documentations in this way.

Comment: Debian is a collection of Free Software, it contains many licenses. There definition of Free, is similar but not the same as that of the Free Software foundation, or the Open Source definition. Therefore should be OK with anything that they distribute. I think that if a licence does not allow it, then it is not  Free Software licensed.

Comment: I don't understand what is it that you are trying to point out.

Comment: There is an answer here https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/6561/1084